# how several enumerations could extend a class that contains methods used for these enumerations in Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, enums, extends

I have two enums, in two packages. I could have 1000 enums, un 1000 packages because I am working on a kind of "unit" architecture and every unit must have its own enum.

I don't want to have every constants in the same enum to maximize the cohesion.

The problem is that every enum is basically the same, excepts for the constants (proper to each unit)

So, I need to repeat a lot of code, and I don't want to do that (my enums implement listeners, and the method logic is a copy/paste in every enum, by example).

I looked over the internet for a enum extension pattern. I found the extensible enum pattern.

It's not exactly what I need.

I am trying to find a solution to keep my constants in differents packages, in differents units, but I would like a kind of abstract class, at the top of the package hierarchy that my enums could extends. That way, I could write the methode logic only one time.

I know that enums can't extends class and they can only implements interfaces.

This is a not working UML sketch that I would like to do:

[image]

How can I do that? Is there a pattern?

how several enumerations could extend a class that contains methods used for these enumerations? (reusable)

**Edit hint:**

I need to use `.values()` from the enum, because I need to iterate with the constants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the "Typesafe Enum" Pattern from the Effective Java book. You can read about it at

http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter5.pdf

Comment: Yes, but the Type same will not allow me to iterate with .values?

Answer (score 1):

you can't extend a class - or an enum - with an enum. But you can implement an interface and delegate the implementation of the methods of the interface to a helper class.

Comment: Yes, a kind of Utility class..? I was actually thinking about it